# PHP 7.1.22 CLI has stopped working windows server 2008 R2

Tags: php, windows-server-2008, bitnami

I'm trying to install a program called 'multicraft' when all the sudden at the end of the installation I get this error
I'm using bitnami
please help me

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: php.exe
  Application Version:  7.1.22.0
  Application Timestamp:    5b99b3e8
  Fault Module Name:    VCRUNTIME140.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.0.6002.24521
  Fault Module Timestamp:   5be7159c
  Exception Code:   c0000135
  Exception Offset: 00000000000b6698
  OS Version:   6.0.6002.2.2.0.305.9
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: fa3e
  Additional Information 2: ac0507478d1c5bd693cfc4fe3987e900
  Additional Information 3: fa3e
  Additional Information 4: ac0507478d1c5bd693cfc4fe3987e900

Read our privacy statement:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=50163&clcid=0x0409
```

Comment: Which version of the installer and Windows are you using? Is it a 64 bits OS? Do you have `Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable` installed in your machine? The `VCRUNTIME140.dll` library is part of this.

Comment: thnx it works now i installed visual c++ 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitnami developer here,

Adding reply with the solution from comments: the `VCRUNTIME140.dll` is part of the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable package. Installing it in your server will fix the issue.

Best regards,

Gonzalo